# WFS requests taking 60 seconds to load

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs, tomcat, apache

I have a website and GeoServer running on an Ubuntu LAMP stack.  GeoServer is running through Tomcat.  Everything is working except WFS requests are taking way too long (~60 seconds).  I have a reverse proxy setup.

```
ProxyVia On

ProxyPass "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/" retry=0 timeout=1000 
ProxyPassReverse "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/"
```

Here's a working wms request:

```
https://digitalcourthouse.com/geoserver/wms/gwc?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=DigitalCourthouse:wv2021gis&styles=&format=image/png8&transparent=true&version=1.1.0&visible=true&identify=true&info_format=application/json&tiled=true&type=WMS&copyright=DCH&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG:3857&bbox=-9012231.382935423,4726254.332929021,-9011619.88670914,4726865.8291553
```

Here's is an example of an WFS that takes too long:

```
https://digitalcourthouse.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=25&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=gispid = '08-03-0034-0002-0000'&typename=DigitalCourthouse:wv2021gis&contentType=application/json
```

And here is a WMS request via proxy.cgi that works:

```
https://digitalcourthouse.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=https://digitalcourthouse.com/geoserver/wms/gwc?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&SRSNAME=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=true&FEATURE_COUNT=1&VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&BBOX=-80.97050428390504%2C39.01739984714393%2C-80.9293055534363%2C39.03208603788136&HEIGHT=881&WIDTH=1920&LAYERS=DigitalCourthouse%3Awv2021gis&QUERY_LAYERS=DigitalCourthouse%3Awv2021gis&SEARCHPARAMS=undefined&BUFFER=5&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&X=327&Y=466
```

How can I get the WFS request to load quicker, or how can I even diagnose why it's taking so long?

Comment: The usual culprit here is the database spatial indices. Because you have spatial indices set, right?

Comment: The store where data comes seems to be very slow. Even this query without any WFS filters takes ages `https://digitalcourthouse.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=25&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&typename=DigitalCourthouse:wv2021gis&contentType=application/json&count=1`. Check the SQL queries that GeoServer is sending (logging level GEOTOOLS_DEVEL) and make your database to answer fast to them.

Answer (score 1):

IvanSanchez was right.  I was missing a spatial index.